# multilevel object traversing and print value based on key

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

Here is my `object`. There could be children inside of children and so on.

I Am trying to print only `name` for all of them.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95hnfwoz/1/)

```
var products = [
        {
        name: 'Allison',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Scott',
                        children: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: 'Sarah',
                children: [],
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Tony',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Lucy',
                children: [],
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far, how can I Print `name` of all children regardless of what level they are in the object??

```
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
    {
    console.log(products[i].name);
    
    if(products[i].children.length > 0) {
        console.log(products[i].children);
        // Print only name of all children.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `recursive` technical.

```js
var products = [ { name: 'Allison', children: [{ name: 'John', children: [ {  name: 'Scott', children: [],},],},{ name: 'Sarah', children: [],},]},{name: 'Tony',children: [{name: 'Lucy',children: [],}]}];
    
const printRecursively = (products) => {
    for (const k of products)
    {
        console.log(k.name);
        k.children.length > 0 &&  printRecursively(k.children); // Recurive here.
    }
}

printRecursively(products);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation, please check
[Also here](https://jsfiddle.net/NverAbgaryan/Lxva1fty/3/)

```js
var products = [
        {
        name: 'Allison',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Scott',
                        children: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: 'Sarah',
                children: [],
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Tony',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Lucy',
                children: [],
            }
        ]
    }
    ];
    
    
function printChildrenNames(children) {
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    console.log(children[i].name);

    if(children[i].children.length > 0) {
      printChildrenNames(children[i].children);
    }
  }
}
printChildrenNames(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). For your use case a simple recursive solution might be the best choice, however this solution is very clean and easily adjustable when requirements change.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ name: 'Allison', children: [{ name: 'John', children: [{ name: 'Scott', children: [] }] }, { name: 'Sarah', children: [] }] }, { name: 'Tony', children: [{ name: 'Lucy', children: [] }] }];

console.log(objectScan(['**.name'], { rtn: 'value', reverse: false })(data));
// => [ 'Allison', 'John', 'Scott', 'Sarah', 'Tony', 'Lucy' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)